# Android going to the wrong activity when button clicked

Tags: android, xamarin, android-activity

In my android  application I have 4 activities:

1. Map (single instance)
2. Configure
3. Clock
4. Finished

The user journey is as follows:

1. The user clicks a button in Map activity which opens the Configure activity.
2. The user then clicks a button on Configure activity and opens the Clock activity.
3. The user then clicks a button on Clock activity and opens the Finish activity.
4. The user then clicks a button on Finish activity and opens the Map activity.
5. The user then goes back to step 1 and starts again.

The journey works fine the first time the user does this. However the second time (step 5) instead of the Configure Activity starting the user is taken to the Finished activity.

My code explicitly starts a new intent for the Configure activity but this seems to be ignored.

The code for the intent is (I am using Xamarin):

```
Intent configure = new Intent(context, typeof(ConfigureActivity));
_context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Do I need to pass some additional flags to force it to open the correct Activity?

Comment: There is more, somewhere else in your code is a bug not in this snippet.

Comment: is that a typo or you are keeping 2 contexts? `context` and `_context`.

Also, where are you calling the `StartActivity` method from?

Answer (score 0):

Well from what I understand the issue seems to be more like a typo you are calling the wrong intent which is, in turn, loading the wrong page.

```
Intent configure = new Intent(context, typeof(ConfigureActivity));
context.StartActivity(configure);
```

Now when you replace your code with this it should call the correct `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem came from my misunderstanding of Android Tasks and how a Task affects which Activity Android loads. I also had a couple of Activity LaunchModes incorrectly configured.

The answer to this question for me was to re-read the Android Task information and also review the Activity LaunchMode and No History settings. I also re-read the documentation on Android task flags.

An overview of the settings I ended up using:

1. Map - SingleTo, Clear Top, New Task
2. Configure -
3. Clock -
4. Finish - Clear Top, No History